# Displaying and parsing real-time command-line output in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pipe

I am writing a command-line Ruby gem for CraftBukkit (of Minecraft fame).

So, CraftBukkit's `.jar` file functions as any command-line server interface should: it accepts user input and sends it to the server when the admin presses enter, while displaying a live feed of server events.

Executed in the command-line directly, then,

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar
```

functions perfectly. I need to execute that same command within my Ruby gem and accept user input in the same way. I am currently using `%x{}` like so:

```
%x{java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar}
```

This functions reasonably well, as it displays output as it should and executes commands typed into the command line window. It does not, however, show user input as it is typed.

I need to fix this. What Ruby commands/frameworks can I use to make the `java` command function perfectly?

If possible, I would also like to be able to parse the output.

I am using [Clamp](https://github.com/mdub/clamp) to parse command line arguments, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
system "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar"
```

do what you wanted? It should at least display the input and output. Or did you want to parse the output from within Ruby?

Comment: That works beautifully! It serves my purposes for now, but are there alternatives that would let me parse it?